# Check AWS Cognito to make sure the email does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Hey everyone so I have the following route below. It works great however I want to be able to check AWS Cognito to make sure the users email does not already exist before I insert them into the RDS database. Is there a simple way to do this? Currently I just insert them and throw an error when they try to login to the site but I really hate that user flow and am trying to make it better. I am using nodejs and the AWS SDK.

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password, plan, isDisplayOwner, optIn } = req.body;
    const bannerToken = null;
    const userAttributes = [
      {
        Name: "given_name",
        Value: req.body.firstName
      },
      {
        Name: "family_name",
        Value: req.body.lastName
      },
      {
        Name: "email",
        Value: req.body.email
      },
      {
        Name: "phone_number",
        Value: req.body.phone
      },
      {
        Name: "custom:company",
        Value: req.body.company
      }
    ];
    await cognito
      .signUp({
        ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
        UserAttributes: userAttributes
      })
      .promise();
    const dbPlanName = plan !== "FREE" ? "Braintree" : plan;

    const [[{ insertId }]] = await database.query(
      "CALL insertUser (?, ?, ?, ?)",
      [username, dbPlanName, isDisplayOwner, bannerToken]
    );

    const paramsId = {
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: "custom:CE_user_id",
          Value: insertId.toString()
        }
      ],
      UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
      Username: username
    };
    await cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes(paramsId).promise();

    if (dbPlanName === "Braintree") {
      await database.query(
        "INSERT INTO pending_subscriptions (user_id, plan) VALUES(?,?)",
        [insertId, plan]
      );
    }

    if (optIn) {
      await database.query(
        "INSERT INTO new_email_list_opt_ins (user_id) VALUES(?)",
        insertId
      );
    }

    res.send("Signup completed. Confirm account.");
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 409;
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Call Cognito ListUsers with a filter on username or email?

Comment: @jarmod could you give me an example thanks

Comment: Some examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#cognito-user-pools-searching-for-users-using-listusers-api

Comment: Are you saying that if you filter on email=bob@exxon.com that it can return more than one user (like bobby@exxon.com)? if so, and it doesn't support 'exact' then filter the results client-side.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but it turns out I had multiple emails of the exact same. Thanks for your help @jarmod. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Everyone here was my solution to search to see if the user exists in cognito. You simply use the listUsers function from the AWS SDK. Note it does not return a boolean but you can just do `emailExists.Users.length` and if the length is greater than 0 the email already exists.

```
    const emailParams = 
    { 
        AttributesToGet: [], 
        Filter: 'email = "' + req.body.email + '"', 
        UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID 
    }; 
    const emailExists = await cognito.listUsers(emailParams).promise()
    if(emailExists.Users.length>0){
        //user exists
        throw "user exists"
    } else {
        // user does not exist
    }
```

Comment: Note that the return value from `await cognito.listUsers(...)` is not a boolean.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Yes I realize its not a Boolean @jarmod however you can check emailExists.Users.length

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24195734)

Comment: @bradbury9 I hope thats a better explaination. Let me know if theres anything else I can do to make it more clear